# Object function Function() { [native code] } has no method '_registerScript'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have site which has updatePanel and it is hosted on a web farm. Ive noticed that sometimes when  I hit ctrl + r there is an js error:

```
Object function Function() { [native code] } has no method '_registerScript'
```

Requests before `ctrl+r` and on `ctrl+r` are made to the same server.

What can be the sause of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a script reference to [MicrosoftAjax.js](http://weblogs.asp.net/wallym/archive/2009/03/17/asp-net-4-0-ajax-preview-release-4-setup.aspx) help?

Comment: it acts randomly, reference is added. Sometimes just by hitting ctrl + r few times this error appears. Normally everything works fine